JDBC Environment Communication Exception while trying to create session factory with Hibernate to connect to RDS MySQL database
This is my Hibernate Module:
@Override
protected void configure() {
    expose(SessionFactory.class);
}

public HibernateModule(final String domain) {
    stage = domain;
    final StringBuilder dbUrlBuilder = new StringBuilder("jdbc:mysql://");
    dbUrlBuilder.append(getHost());
    dbUrlBuilder.append(":");
    dbUrlBuilder.append(getPort());
    dbUrlBuilder.append("/");
    dbUrlBuilder.append(getDbName());
    dbUrl = dbUrlBuilder.toString();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Configuration getConnectionConfiguration() {
    log.info(getUsername());
    log.info(getPassword());
    final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", dbUrl);
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", getUsername());
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", getPassword());
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    conf.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "false");
    return conf;
}

@Provides
ServiceRegistry getServiceRegistry(final Configuration configuration) {
    return new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
}

@Provides
MetadataSources getSources(final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry,
                           @Named("entities") final List<Class<?>> entityClasses) {
    final MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
    entityClasses.forEach(sources::addAnnotatedClass);
    return sources;
}

@Provides
@Named("entities")
List<Class<?>> getEntityAnnotatedClasses() {
    final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(NAMESPACE);
    return new ArrayList<>(reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class));
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Metadata getMetadata(final MetadataSources sources) {
    return sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
SessionFactory getSessionFactory(final Metadata metadata) {
    return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
}

These are major versions of my dependencies.
MysqlConnectorJava = 8.0.x;
Hibernate = 5.6.5;

The error I am getting is:

Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)\n\t... 83 more\nCaused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)\n\t... 87 more\nCaused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)\n\tat java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

I have verified my database credentials, they are correct. My database is up and running (connected through MySQL workbench). The security group of my RDS instances allow inbound connections from my Guice Service's ipv4 cidr block. The RDS instance is publicly accesible.
Has anyone faced this issue or know how to debug/proceed in this situation?
